# ¿Para qué sirve imp.reload()?

Tags: python

Busqué información de `imp.reload()` de Python pero no llego entender ¿Para qué puede servir?

**Me podrían explicar con algunos ejemplos** se los agradezco ya de antemano

Answer (score 5):

### Introducción

Primero de todo la librería `imp` está fuera de uso, y no te la recomiendo salvo que estés en Python 2.7. En Python 3 está la libreria `importlib` que es la encargada de realizar las importaciones y el manejo de librerías y módulos. **Esta es la librería actual y con mantenimiento encargada de ello**, no `imp`

### Para que sirve reload()

Dicho esto, en ambas librerías se encuentra la función `.reload()`. Esta función sirve para **cuando estás desarrollando un paquete** de Python, y estás probando distintos desarrollos y funcionamientos. Lo que haces es recargar de nuevo tu librería de cero, evitando tener que reiniciar el interprete de Python.

Si te has encontrado antes en esta situación, y no conocias `reload()` siempre tienes que reiniciar el interprete de Python, volver a cargar paquetes, volver a cargar variables, insufrible... (Esto sucede por la forma de Python de cargar las librerías, tema en el que no voy a entrar ya que me desviaría de la pregunta)

En resumen `reload()` **hace que le pases un módulo/paquete y lo reinicia, para evitarte reiniciar el interprete.**

Por ejemplo:

```
import numpy 
import importlib

importlib.reload(numpy) #Reiniciamos el módulo numpy
```

### Explicación práctica detallada

Tenemos la siguiente organización de carpetas:

```
prueba_reload
|
|---- operaciones
|        |
|        |------__init__.py
```

Tenemos una carpeta **operaciones** y dentro el fichero `__init__.py` donde vamos a desarrollar nuestro propio módulo de operaciones.

Así es nuestro **init**.py:

```
def suma(a, b):
    return a , b
```

Con el interprete de Python **en el path donde se encuentre** *prueba_reload*, Abrimos el interprete ejecutando `python` y podemos ejecutar los siguientes comandos

```
>>> import operaciones
>>> a = 4
>>> b = 7
>>> operaciones.suma(a, b)
```

**Salida:** `(4, 7)`

Obviamente hemos realizado mal nuestra operación suma, vamos a cambiarla:

```
def suma(a, b):
    return a + b
```

**Si NO usamos** `reload()` tenemos que volver a realizar todo lo anterior, ya que Python va al **Cache** para cargar la librería, y allí se encuentra nuestra librería antigua, sin las modificaciones, si queremos usar la librería con el cambio realizado tenemos que.

1. Salir del interprete de Python
2. Abrir un nuevo interprete de Python
3. importar nuestra función `suma()`
4. Crear las variables `a` y `b`
5. Ejecutar las operaciones que queremos volver a probar, es decir `suma()`

Como puedes ver esto es una autentica locura, si esto sucede con una función tan simple, imaginate si estás desarrollando un algoritmo por ejemplo, que necesitas cargar gran cantidad de datos, modificarlos, correr el algoritmo, etc. Además de hacer bastante tedioso cualquier cambio, sería una perdida de tiempo importante.

Como conocemos la función `reload()` no es necesario hacer todo lo anterior. simplemente ejecutamos:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.reload(operaciones) #Recargamos nuestra librería
```

**Salida:** `module 'operaciones' from '.../prueba_reload/operaciones/__init__.py'>`

Y seguidamente sin salir del interprete ejecutamos de nuevo la suma:

```
>>> operaciones.suma(a, b)
```

**Salida:** `11`

¡Esto nos permite probar nuestros cambios al instante!

Comment: Yo cambiaría "terminal" por "intérprete", por no inducir a error. Y de paso menciono que esto suele ser realmente útil cuando el intérprete es IPython o Jupyter Notebook, ya que así evitas tener que reiniciar el kernel y perder todos los cálculos ya ejecutados en las diferentes celdas.

Comment: Y yo reiniciando el _kernel_ como un tonto cada vez que realizaba cambios... bravo!!.